# Get max key value pair from dictionary, but with key restrictions

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, max

Imagine I have a dictionary like this:

```
{(0,0) : 5 , (0,1) : 7 , (0,2) : 9 , (1,0) : 1 , (1,1) : 3 , (1,2) : 20 , (2,0) : 6 , (2,1) : 5 , (2,2) : 25 }
```

Is there a way to get the max key value pair, but with only taking into account keys with certain values?

For example, if I wanted the max pair from when the first index of the key is 0. So the max between:

```
 {(0,0) : 5 , (0,1) : 7 , (0,2) : 9}
```

Which would be `(0,2) : 9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a comprehension with an if clause to get all the relevant elements, and then get the max value with `max()`:

```
max(value for key, value in d.items() if key[0] == 0)
```

A more general case would be something like:

```
max(value for key, value in d.items() if predicate(key, value))
```

Where `predicate` is some function which returns a boolean.

For getting both the key and value, you can use the following:

```
d = {(0,0) : 5 , (0,1) : 7 , (0,2) : 9 , (1,0) : 1 , (1,1) : 3 , (1,2) : 20 , (2,0) : 6 , (2,1) : 5 , (2,2) : 25 }
max_key = max({k: v for k, v in d.items() if k[0] == 0}, key=d.get)
max_value = d[max_key]
```

Note that there may be several keys with the max value.

Comment: Does it work for the corresponding key? When I tried it, it worked for getting the max value, but for the key it always returns (0,2) even when the corresponding value is not the max

Comment: I've edited the answer to include this option as well.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `filter` to filter out the required keys from the original dictionary. In this case, keys which have `0` at the 0th index.

```py
def filter_function(item):
    key, value = item
    return key[0] == 0

def max_key(item):
    key, value = item
    return value

print(max(filter(filter_function, dictionary.items()), key=max_key))
```

The `filter_function` could be replaced with whatever condition you'd like to have.

Comment: I tried it and it always returns (0,2), even when the corresponding value is not the max, my objective would be to get the pair with the highest value

Comment: I've updated the answer accordingly.